# Plotting list of functions using for loop in R

Tags: r, plot

How can you plot a list of functions in one graph using a `for` loop in R? The following code does the trick, but requires a separate call of `plot` for the first function outside of the `for` loop, which is very clunky. Is there a way to handle all the plotting inside the `for` loop without creating multiple plots?

```
vec <- 1:10
funcs <- lapply(vec, function(base){function(exponent){base^exponent}})

x_vals <- seq(0, 10, length.out=100)
plot(x_vals, funcs[[1]](x_vals), type="l", ylim=c(0,100))
for (i in 2:length(vec)) {
  lines(x_vals, funcs[[i]](x_vals))
}
```

Comment: You still need the first function to define the x and y limits. Base R plots don't update the view region when you add additional elements. Would you rather use something like ggplot instead of base R?

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! Maybe I ought to switch to `ggplot`, I just like keeping imports to a minimum, but only so much can be done. I think I just found a work-around, I'll post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do the computations first and plotting after, like this:

```r
vec <- 1:10
funcs <- lapply(vec, function(base) function(exponent){base^exponent})

x_vals <- seq(0, 10, length.out=100)
y_vals <- sapply(funcs, \(f) f(x_vals))
plot(1, xlim=range(x_vals), ylim=range(y_vals), type='n', log='y', 
     xlab='x', ylab='y')
apply(y_vals, 2, lines, x=x_vals)
```

This way you know the range of your *y* values before initiating the plot and can set the *y* axis limits accordingly (if you would want that). Note that I chose to use logarithmic *y* axis here.

[image: R plot]

Answer (score 0):

Based on MrFlick's comment, it looks like something like this would be one way to do what I'm looking for, but is still not great.

```r
vec <- 1:10
funcs <- lapply(vec, function(base){function(exponent){base^exponent}})

x_vals <- seq(0, 10, length.out=100)
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,100))
for (i in 1:length(vec)) {
  lines(x_vals, funcs[[i]](x_vals))
}
```